# Как сделать чтобы ReclerView стал не кликабельным

Tags: android, cardview, setonclicklistener

У меня есть `CardView` в котором `LinearLayout`и`RecyclerView`, при нажатии на `CardView` работает `setOnClickListener`, но если я нажимаю в область `RecyclerView`,`setOnClickListener` не работает. Как сделать так чтобы `RecyclerView`не мешал нажатию `CardView`?

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_h_faq"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="0dp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/ll_faq"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingStart="6dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="6dp">

                                <ProgressBar
                                    android:id="@+id/prgs_2"
                                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/color_11"
                                    android:paddingEnd="6dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                                    android:visibility="gone"
                                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/iiiii"
                                    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
                                    android:text="Часто задаваемые вопросы"
                                    android:textColor="@drawable/color_profile"
                                    android:textSize="24sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/prgs_2" />

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:padding="1dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
                                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                    app:tint="@drawable/color_profile" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/Rec_H_FAQ"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_faq"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />
                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/ll_faq"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg_overlay"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

```
 card_h_faq = requireView().findViewById(R.id.card_h_faq);
        card_h_faq.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentFAQ fragment = new FragmentFAQ(); // you fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(); // instantiate your view context
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim,
                    R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim, R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);// your container and your fragment
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("Profile");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        });
```

Comment: нужен код, где ты назначаешь setOnClickListener

Comment: @DrMcSheen обновил вопрос

Comment: Если вы нажимаете не на CardView то что и чему мешает ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, можно немного исправить `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`. Создадим собственный класс, наследуемый от него:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

public class CustomCardView extends CardView {

    public CustomCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    };

    public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    };

    public CustomCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return true;
    };
}
```

Тогда в разметке используйте его так:

```
<com.example.app.CustomCardView
   ...>
   ...
</com.example.app.CustomCardView>
```

Больше об `onInterceptTouchEvent` [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)).